# Efficient way to write 2^20 files to ext4 filesystem

Tags: php, performance, file, unix, ext4

I'm trying to write 2^20 files with about 45k lines in each, each line is a word.
I need this to be flat, no sql for storage purpose, I optimized it not to take too much disk space.

As of now the files are written in 16 directory, making it 65536 file in each directory. The file names are 4 characters long.

That didn't seem too much for me, my script takes a huge file, read each line, and then write each line in its dedicated file.

I first tried to make this with 2^16 files, so 4096 files in each directory, worked like a charm but I wanted to make the lookup faster. It seems to hit a wall at this number of files. Yet from what I saw on the internet, it's not even close the ext4 maximum file number.

After say 45gB it became very very very slow (like wrote 100 lines in each file in more than an hour).

My script is taking advantage of the server 64gB ram by having a buffer, I have 1.7tB SSD drive with more than 700mB writing speed but still looks like it cannot manage that much files. Even a du -h /dir/ takes forever.

Is there any way to do this task faster, or should I just go with 65536 files ?

Thank you for your help :)
Have a great day.

EDIT : Here's the code sorry for the mistake.

Thank you for your answer and sorry I didn't post any code. Here's the code :

```
    $time_pre = microtime(true);
$bufferSize = (1<<9);
$dico = fopen('/path/to/file1',"r+");
$hexa = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
for($i = 0;$i < 16;$i++)
{
    for($j = 0;$j < 16;$j++)
    {
        for($k = 0;$k < 16;$k++)
        {
            for($l = 0;$l < 16;$l++)
            {
                for($m = 0;$m < 16;$m++)
                {
                    $ijklm = "$hexa[$i]$hexa[$j]$hexa[$k]$hexa[$l]$hexa[$m]";
                    $$ijklm = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
while(!feof($dico))
{
    $ligne = rtrim(fgets($dico));

    $md4 =  hash("md5",$ligne);
    $add4 = "$md4[0]$md4[1]$md4[2]$md4[3]$md4[4]";
    $$add4 .= "$md4[5]$md4[6]$ligne\n";
    if(isset($$add4{$bufferSize}))
    {
        $baseFichier = '/path/to/'.$md4[0].'/'.$md4[1].'/'.$md4[2].'/'.$md4[3].'/'.$md4[4];
        $fichier = fopen($baseFichier,"a");
        fwrite($fichier, $$add4);
        fclose($fichier);
        $$add4 = "";
    }
}
    for($i = 0;$i < 16;$i++)
    {
        for($j = 0;$j < 16;$j++)
        {
            for($k = 0;$k < 16;$k++)
            {
                for($l = 0;$l < 16;$l++)
                {
                    for($m = 0;$m < 16;$m++)
                    {
                        $ijklm = "$hexa[$i]$hexa[$j]$hexa[$k]$hexa[$l]$hexa[$m]";
                        if($$ijklm != "")
                        {
                            $baseFichier = '/Path/to/'.$hexa[$i].'/'.$hexa[$j].'/'.$hexa[$k].'/'.$hexa[$l].'/'.$hexa[$m];
                            $fichier = fopen($baseFichier,"a");
                            fwrite($fichier, $$ijkl);
                            fclose($fichier);
                            $$ijklm = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

fclose($dico);
```

I used fflush and some locks for the files at first, because I had 6 workers at the same time, to avoid writing problems. But for testing sake I removed it. On this one I tried to create 16^4 directories instead of one directory with 65.536 files in it.
I also tried a smaller buffer, to check if this was better on SSD.

It's running right now but looks like it's slower than previous test. The input file is 75gig, I have 6 like this to process.

What would you do to speed things up ?
I'm using php8. I tried using C but was the same issue so I went with a more high-level language for facility purpose.

Thank you :)

PS : Sorry if the code isn't pro it's a hobbie for me.

Comment: without an [mcve] we can only guess. But with 45GB in data, I can imagine several scenarios where your code is not optimized for size and is causing the OS to swap, which could easily produce a symptom like 100 lines per hour. AND ... StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  so  please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Err, 2**20 is just a million - which should be easy. How are you assigning the names if they only have 4 letters each because 26*26*26*26 only gives 450,000 filenames so maybe you are getting hash collisions.

Comment: Initially you say each file has 45k lines, then later you say you take one line and write each line in a dedicated file. So does each file have 1 line or 45,000? Thank you.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. As you can see the names are hexa so no problem of collision, each name' unique. For the files they'll end up with 45k lines if I manage to go through this, because I have a 46 billion file to process, on this code you see file1 which is 75gig long, but there's 5 more files to process. Maybe i'll try to make several if I manage to get to a correct speed. Thanks again

Comment: I get to a point now (5 billion lines wrote, 5000 in each file) where the cpu is not even loading to 100% on one core, it's staying at 10/15%, while iostat give me a 5 to 8mib writing speed. Don't get where's the bottleneck. Even when the process start, 100% cpu but only 30 to 70mib/s writing on iostat, far away from what SSD are capable, I guess there's too much files to open/close.

Comment: Can you add the [tag:php] tag please? Maybe drop [tag:server] or [tag:file]. I still think you are likely going to cause problems for the directory index with your naming scheme.

Comment: I was thinking, maybe i could split the naming scheme by only doing say 0 to 7 first then 8 to f after ? Still can't see what would cause perf issue, i don't have any duplicate in names and doesn't to be an incredible amount of files to process. Ssd latency may be in cause no? For 1ms latency i guess that much files would cause a bottleneck, but i just tried with a 1<<14 buffer, 25gig of ram used but still very slow.

Comment: Maybe try and break the problem down. Try reading the dico file but not creating any output files at all. Try to create the files all empty and see how long that takes to run and how long `du` and `ls -l` take. Then try creating say 10kB of static text in memory and write that same content in each file and time that.

Comment: I'm trying that right now. It seems reading the file goes to about 80mib/s which is correct though kind of slow for a ssd. The slower thing (except writing files I didn't try that yet) seem to be filling the array, here the reading drops down to 8mib/s. Maybe I could try to fread large chunks of data then split the lines by newline character ? I'll bench that.

Comment: Ok I tried to debug the code by adding some timers, but it seems that the writing process just takes too much time after files got bigger, at first it's ok, processing about 2 billion lines in one hour, but then it's getting slower and slower. Guess it's what it is, too much fopen and fclose in the loop, but cannot open more than 1024 files. I'll go back to 16^4 files. Would you have any idea on how to optimize speed and storage for this too ? I'm using zgrep now but I would like to use xzgrep to store more data, but then with files being bigger it takes time to process.

Comment: It's really quite hard to help. I have no idea what you are really trying to do, nor what your input or output files really look like, nor do I know what OS you are using, nor why you can't have more file descriptors open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The input looks like a dictionnary, one word per line. The script takes that word, hash it, then store the word in a file that will match the first letters of the hash. Then I grep thru files to find a word according to a given hash. That's basically rainbow tables. I'm using debian server 10, file descriptors are maxed at 1024 according to the command ulimit -n.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this. If you have 1,000,000 files with 45,000 lines in each, you have 45,000,000,000 hashes, correct? How can it be faster to look up a hash across 1,000,000 files than just calculate it on demand?

Comment: The rainbow tables are created in order to unhash not to hash, since hashing is a one way function if you want to know what's behind a hash you hae to bruteforce or to have access to rainbow tables. You can find a lot of them online, mine isn't big compared to others, for instance cmd5 has 25.000 billions hashes stored.